# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in file.php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
$productQuery     = "SELECT ean, name FROM products WHERE category = '$category'";
$productResult    = $mysqli->query($productQuery);

while ($productRow = $productResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $productPriceQuery     = "SELECT ean, price+shipmentCost AS totalPrice FROM prices WHERE ean = $productRow[ean] ORDER BY totalPrice ASC";
    $productPriceResult    = $mysqli->query($productPriceQuery);

    $totalPrice            = $productPriceResult->fetch_assoc();

    echo $productPriceResult["productURL"];
}
```

But I am getting the following error for the echo line:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in file.php
```

I already read some articles on this website and other websites but did not understand the problem and could not solve it myself.

Comment: It seems that `$productPriceResult` is a sql result, not a fetched array. Is "productURL" stored in the `products` table?

Comment: It is stored in table 'prices'.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

`$productPriceResult` is a result, not a fetched array.

It seems like "productURL" should be stored in the `products` table, but for the sake of explanation I'll keep it how you have it: in the `prices` table.

You'll need to add "productURL" to your `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT ean, productURL, price+shipmentCost AS totalPrice FROM prices ...
```

And access "productURL" like this:

```
$totalPrice['productURL'];
```

Incidentally, the price will be accessed like this:

```
$totalPrice['totalPrice'];
```

I recommend renaming the `$totalPrice` variable to `$priceData` or something more appropriate.

### Edit:

Here's an example of how to loop through the price data.
I've truncated the actual query string for readability.

```
// loop through rows fetched from "products" table
while ($productRow = $productResult->fetch_assoc()) {

    // query price data for this product
    $productPriceQuery     = "SELECT ean, productURL, etc...";
    $productPriceResult    = $mysqli->query($productPriceQuery);

    // loop through rows fetched from "prices" table
    while ($priceData = $productPriceResult->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<p>".$priceData['productURL']."</p>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Stupid me :) I indeed have to use $totalPrice instead of $productPriceResult. Now it is partly working. I have 5 records in the table, 3x ean 123 and 2x ean 567. But is giving only 1 result.

Comment: Nah, not stupid -- computers are just not very understanding ;). Which part is left not working? Or is that better as a separate post?

Comment: Are you referring to the `prices` table? If so, you are only fetching from that table once per product. That only fetches the first returned row. To fetch more rows, you'll need a loop like the `while` loop you used for your first query.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to illustrate the second loop.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
public function DisplayProducts() {
    $productQuery     = "SELECT ean, name FROM products WHERE category = '$category'";
    $productResult    = $this->mysqli->query($productQuery);

    while ($productRow = $productResult->fetch_object()) {
        $productPriceQuery     = "SELECT ean, price+shipmentCost AS totalPrice FROM prices WHERE ean = $productRow->ean ORDER BY totalPrice ASC";
        $productPriceResult = $this->mysqli->query($productPriceQuery);

        while($row=$productPriceResult->fetch_object()) {
        $ProductPrice = $row->totalPrice;
        $ProductURL = $row->productURL; //I'm not seeing where you're querying for the URL so you'll have to append accordingly.
            }
    }
```

And then Create your table you're talking about.

```
   echo "<table><th>Product Price</th><th>Product URL</th>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $ProductPrice . "</td><td>" . $ProductURL . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Hopefully there's some help on where to start there. Good luck.

Comment: Do everyone a favor and if you're going to downvote at least tell everyone your reasoning. :)